# Unable to locate elements on a website , i tried all the locators but I get the error "No such element" . I am a self taught beginner to Automation

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

Element HTML:

```
<a href="/cacApp/Main/INBOX" title="View the Inbox" target="main">Inbox</a>
```

What I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[text='Log out']"));
```

then

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Log out']"));
```

Element snapshot:

[image]HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log out"));
```

Something like that should work, you should provide the page html for a better response.

My response is based on the fact that in your first try you are saying text='Log out'.
findElement in selenium works with locatorStrategies (By.cssSelector/By.linkText...) the one that i used (linkText) search in all the anchor tags that are found in the pages () and analyze the text inside the tag, if the text is matched the driver will find the element.

Let me know if it works, otherwise provide me the web page html snippet.

I've seen the actual screen, you must change Log out with Inbox

```
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Inbox"));
```

Comment: I've seen the editet question, this should work.
The css selector will not because the elemant has no class, the xpath is a bit more complex because we might need the full page to provide you an answer.

Comment: I have added the snippet of the HTML , the solution provided didn't work either. Thank you so much.

Comment: edited, try with the last code snippet that i've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<a href="/cacApp/Main/INBOX" title="View the Inbox" target="main">Inbox</a>
```

You need to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

- Within *cssSelector* doesn't supports the *`:contains("text")`* method
- Within *xpath* for exact text matches you need to use *`text()`*

---

### Solution

To identify the element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *linkText*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log out"));
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href$='INBOX'][title='View the Inbox']"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Inbox' and @title='View the Inbox']"));
  ```

Comment: I tried everything and still failed. It appears my elements were hidden inside an iframe so i had to use the below line:

 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iframeName")));

Comment: Okay, once you switch the frame I'm sure my suggested line of code would work

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.